# Get href link and add a value to it via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I made a code in which I am trying to add the quantity of the product when a user types in the quantity he.she wants for that product. the problem is I am not able to select the `anchor` via jquery to get the `href` link so that I can add new value to it.

My code:

```
$('.mival').keyup(function(event) {
    var i=$(this).parents(".cart").next('.milink').attr('href');
    alert(i);
});
```

When I try to alert it says `undefined`

My Markup of html:

```
<div class="cart">
       <div><strong>Price:</strong> <span>$20.30</span></div>
            <div><strong> Qty:</strong><span>
                <input type="text" class="mival" value="1" />
             </span></div>
<a class="milink" href="http://example.com/vid=3">Add to Cart </a> </div>
```

I have not yet written the code for adding the value to the link I can do that. the problem is how to get value from this markup's `a` element so that I can get the `href` link .

Comment: I see no element with the `cart` class.

Comment: i changed the class name to container. i changed it back to class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do `not` have any parent with class `cart`, using div instead can do the trick. Alternatively you can use `closest('.container')`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EySrB/)**

```
$('.mival').keyup(function(event) {
    var i=$(this).parents("div").next('.milink').attr('href');
    alert(i);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You also have a missing `>` at the end of `<div class="container"`.

```
$(this).closest(".container").children('a.milink')
```

ex:

```
$('.mival').keyup(function(event) {
    var i = $(this).closest(".container").children('a.milink').attr('href');
    alert(i);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BgrsJ/)

Comment: yes . it works . i tried thanks to you too :) ill voteup for u as soon as i am granted permissions lol. I am new